# React: rendering a variable set in useEffect() is always one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

Working on an application for Android using React Native, I stumbled upon a strange issue.

There is a SearchBar to perform a name search on a database. The result should be rendered. In the code below, you see I set the variable with the result in `useEffect()`-Hook after defining the variable outside using `useRef()`: `let returnValue = useRef('No results');`

So I expected that if I type a name, such as "Mike", the database result (stored in `returnValue.current`) will be rendered immediately after submitting.

But no.

Actually, the result "Mike" is rendered after I open the Search Bar again and delete the last character, leaving "Mik". Then the application renders "Mike", as if it was exactly one step behind.

After searching for the issue, I just found async "problems" with `useState()`-Hook, but not with `useEffect()`. When I do `console.log()` the `useState()`, everything is set correctly. Even inside `useEffect()`- logging `returnValue.current` always gives the correct result in the correct time. The one single issue is the rendering of `returnValue.current` with that strange delay.

Is someone able to demystify this behavior?

```
import ...

const SearchBar = props => {
  let [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(null);
  let returnValue = useRef('No results');

  const sendInputValueToReduxStore = text => {
    setInputValue(text);
    props.setInputValueSearchBar(text);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // setting database schema
    const personsSchema = {
      name: 'realm',
      properties: {
        name: 'string?',
        color: 'string?',
      },
    };

    // open the database
    let database = new Realm({
      path: fs.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/default.realm',
      schema: [personsSchema ],
      readOnly: true,
    });

    // doing the database query
    const allPersons = database.objects('realm');
    let resultArray = [];
    const query = inputValue;
    const queryResult = inputValue
      ? allPersons.filtered("name == '" + query + "'")
      : 'default';
    resultArray = Array.from(queryResult);
    const personNamesArray = resultArray.map(value => value.name);
    const personNames = personNamesArray.toString();
    returnValue.current = personNames;
    // logging always correct
    console.log('person name: ', personNames);
  }, [inputValue]);

  const isText = props.text;

  return (
    <View>
      <Header searchBar rounded>
        <Item>
          <Icon name="ios-search" />
          <Input
            placeholder="Search"
            onChangeText={text => sendInputValueToReduxStore(text)}
            value={inputValue}
          />
        </Item>
      </Header>
      {isText && (
        <View>
          <Text>{props.text}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      //returnValue.current is rendered with delay
      {returnValue && <Text>{returnValue.current}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you are use useRef in this situation? Why not just use an additional useState to set the computed persons value? Also you may consider avoiding establishing a new database connection inside every single iteration of useEffect.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks for your reply. I use useRef() because when I assign the variable with useState(), following error is thrown: Assignments to the 'returnValue' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. --> So I did what is recommended in this message and used useRef().

Comment: Right if you try to save to a variable it will give that error, I mean entirely replacing returnValue with a new useState hook for getting setting return value as you are doing with inputValue. `const [returnValue, setReturnValue] = useState([]); // ... setReturnValue(personNames);`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Do you maybe have an example for a poor beginner? ^^ I feel that I don't really get what you're meaning.

Comment: Here is a contrived example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sntucz . I really just mean replacing `useRef` with `useState` and setting the value of "returnValue" inside useEffect after you query/filter/process the persons.

Comment: Glad to hear. I added an answer to outline the possible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `useRef` hook with just `useState` hook. It should be enough as `returnValue` is just a computed value derived from `inputValue`:

```
import ...

const SearchBar = props => {
  let [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(null);
  let [returnValue, setReturnValue] = useState(null);

  const sendInputValueToReduxStore = text => {
    setInputValue(text);
    props.setInputValueSearchBar(text);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // setting database schema
    const personsSchema = {
      name: 'realm',
      properties: {
        name: 'string?',
        color: 'string?',
      },
    };

    // open the database
    let database = new Realm({
      path: fs.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/default.realm',
      schema: [personsSchema ],
      readOnly: true,
    });

    // doing the database query
    const allPersons = database.objects('realm');
    let resultArray = [];
    const query = inputValue;
    const queryResult = inputValue
      ? allPersons.filtered("name == '" + query + "'")
      : 'default';
    resultArray = Array.from(queryResult);
    const personNamesArray = resultArray.map(value => value.name);
    const personNames = personNamesArray.toString();
    setReturnValue(personNames);
  }, [inputValue]);

  const isText = props.text;

  return (
    <View>
      <Header searchBar rounded>
        <Item>
          <Icon name="ios-search" />
          <Input
            placeholder="Search"
            onChangeText={text => sendInputValueToReduxStore(text)}
            value={inputValue}
          />
        </Item>
      </Header>
      {isText && (
        <View>
          <Text>{props.text}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      {returnValue && <Text>{returnValue}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
};
```